# jQuery index() does not return the correct position

Tags: jquery

I want to know the index of an element with a specifical id on a list.
I write an example of what I want on this fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/c4n0q53e/
I just used what the jQuery documentation said...

```
var index = $("li").index("#is-selected")
$(".result").html(index);
```

Do someone see what's is the problem on this simple code ?

Comment: `var index = $("#is-selected").index();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter for `index` is an element not the selector.
This works:

```
var index = $("li").index($("#is-selected"))
```

Answer (score 2):

shouldnt it be more like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/7vwg7g97/1/

```
var index = $("#is-selected").index("li")
$(".result").html(index);
```

this looks for `#is-selected` within the results of the selector `li`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4n0q53e/2/)

```
var var1 = $("#is-selected").index();
$(".result").append(var1);
```